# Apache error "could not bind to adress"

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, arch-linux

Since the last update, apache won't start anymore...
I have this message :

> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
> address [::]:80
>
> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could
> not bind to address [::]:443

When I try to see who is listening (`netstat -plant`) i don't see any process on those ports... They are also wide opened on my iptables. Any ideas ?

Btw I'm on Archlinux (4.4.75-1-MANJARO) and using Apache 2.4.26.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple configuration files with the Listen statements in them now ?

Comment: Okay I got it ! When updating, pacman overrided my httpd-vhosts.conf file... Thanks @marcolz ^^

Comment: Glad you got it working! Please add your comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got it !
For some reasons Pacman overrided my httpd-vhosts.conf file. Then in had multiple `Listen 80` & `Listen 443` in my Apache config files.

That's strange that Pacman didn't created a httpd-vhosts.conf.pacnew instread of overriding my file but it's not and Apache issue.